# How do I resize my image when zooming in or out with the browser zoom tool?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have my images scale when i zoom in by 150% but my image stays the same

100% zoom

[image: 100% zoom]

150% zoom

[image: 150% zoom]

```
<img class="planner" src="images/planner.png" alt="planner-img" height="526" width="526">

.planner{
    width:25%;
    float: left; 
    margin-bottom: 100%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: I Think That's because you've set the height and width in Image tag itself. Try mentioning it in your css and for any changes you can always add media queries..

Comment: Because you have defined width and height in Image tag, I assume it will be given preference. Try removing width and height from image tag and apply it using CSS class, and just give width or height and the other as auto. Or you can also detect browser resize event and then apply width or height accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use px instead of % in width
like this:

```css
.planner{
    width:250px;
    float: left; 
    margin-bottom: 100%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height:auto;
    
}
```